# Soap fail function response

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have a SOAP client code to get auto parts  from elit company but I have a strange result.

```
object(stdClass)[225]
  public 'return' => 
    object(stdClass)[226]
      public 'unitPrice' => float 0
      public 'vat' => int 0
```

My php code:

> getItem function must have an array parameters:

```
7 => string 'struct getItem {
     string company;
     string login;
     string password;
     string activeItemNo; }

public function demo($piesa)
{

    $wsdl = 'http://icelit02.elit.cz:7606/InterCompany-1.10.0/BuyerService?wsdl';
    $opts = array('http' => array('protocol_version' => '1.0'));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('stream_context' => $context));


    var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
    var_dump($client->__getTypes());
    $response=$client->__call('getItem', array(array('company'=>'ELIT_RO', 'login'=>'autocomplet15', 'password'=>'elena10', 'activeItemNo'=>'M043 22 00'))); 
    dd($response);
    }
```

Comment: You can call directly `$client->getItem($arguments)`. Can you show the `__getFunctions` result as well? Be aware of showing your passwords here.

Comment: I believe, you should not use nested array, just simple array as an agrument: `$response = $client->getItem(array('company'=>'ELIT_RO', 'login'=>'login', 'password'=>'password', 'activeItemNo'=>'M043 22 00'));`

Comment: Honza Haering : if I call getItem directly, I receive an error: Function not found...or something like this.

Comment: What is the output of the `var_dump($client->__getFunctions());` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item with `'activeItemNo'=>'M043 22 00'` doesn't exist in the catalogue. Try with some existing, e.g. `'activeItemNo'=>'ATE 390569'`.